# Java word shuffle game

Tags: java

I'm having tons of issues with this program. I can't get my string comparisons to work and I have several infinite loops that I'm not sure how to fix. I would appreciate a fresh set of eyes to show me what I'm missing, I've been staring at this for 3 days and I keep skipping over my errors. The program needs to pick a random word from the given text file, scramble up that word, then have the user guess what the original word was. Hints should display what letter is at a given random position within the word.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Proj4 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
        int wordScore = 10; 
        int score = 0;
        boolean game = true;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        char responseLetter = 'n';
        boolean allTrue = false;
        boolean scramble = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
        int counter = 0;
        int position = 0;   

        System.out.println("Enter in a file containing words (Ex: words.txt) : ");
        String filename = in.nextLine();
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));           

        String size = inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(size);
        int arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(size);
        String[] wordList = new String[arrayLength];
        Random rndm = new Random();  
        while (inFile.hasNext()) {    
        // this section puts the contents of the text file into the array        
            wordList[i] = inFile.nextLine(); 
            i++;
        }

        while (game == true) {       
            // System.out.println("Current puzzle: " + scrambledWord); 
            // System.out.println("Current points for word " + wordScore);
            // System.out.println("Enter (g)uess, (n)ew word, (h)int, or (q)uit: ");
            //  responseLetter = in.next().charAt(0);
            if (responseLetter == 'n') {     
                // goes back to the beginning but does not change word. I cant move the picker down becauase it throws off g 
                String pickedWord = wordList[rndm.nextInt(arrayLength )];
                boolean [] used = new boolean[pickedWord.length()] ; // the random word gets picked here                
                String [] letters = pickedWord.split("");
                while (allTrue == false) {  
                    int randomLetter = rndm.nextInt(pickedWord.length());
                    if (used[randomLetter] != true) {
                        sb.append(letters[randomLetter].charAt(0)); // does this line work?
                        used[randomLetter] = true;    
                    } else if (used[randomLetter]== true) {
                        scramble = true;
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if (counter > (2 * pickedWord.length())) {
                        allTrue = true;
                    }
                }
                String scrambledWord = sb.toString();
                if (scrambledWord.equals(pickedWord)) {
                    System.out.println("The words match");
                    allTrue = false;
                }          
                System.out.println("Current puzzle: " + scrambledWord); 
                System.out.println("Current points for word " + wordScore);
                System.out.println("Enter (g)uess, (n)ew word, (h)int, or (q)uit: ");
                responseLetter = in.next().charAt(0);
            } else if (responseLetter == 'g') {  
                // automatically says guess is wrong. something wrong with equals()?    
                System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
                in.nextLine();
                String guess = in.nextLine();

                if (guess.equals(pickedWord)) {               
                    System.out.println("You guessed it!");
                    score += wordScore;
                    game = true;
                } else if (!guess.equals(pickedWord)) {
                    System.out.println("Oops! Try again.");
                    wordScore--;

                    System.out.println("Current points for word " + wordScore);
                    System.out.println("Enter (g)uess, (n)ew word, (h)int, or (q)uit: ");
                    responseLetter = in.next().charAt(0);

                }
            } else if (responseLetter == 'h') { 
                //THIS BLOCK WORKS. DONT EVEN LOOK AT IT
                Random r = new Random();
                int hint = r.nextInt(pickedWord.length());
                System.out.println(hint);
                char letterAtSpot = pickedWord.charAt(hint);
                System.out.println("The letter at spot " + hint + " is " + letterAtSpot);
                wordScore--;

            } else if (responseLetter == 'q') {
                game = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Choice - 'g', 'n', 'h', 'q' only.");
                responseLetter = 'n';
            }
        }
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            System.out.println("Total score: " + score);

    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm having tons of issues with this program." is not proper problem description which someone with same problem could use to find this question. Please be more specific about what specific problem you are facing. Try to limit your code to [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and make your code readable by using proper indentation (almost any editor has tools for that). It will also help *you* find most obvious problems.

Comment: @Nikki Harding - I see you're a student of computer science... while I do agree that this question is kind of vague, you should probably get used to this kind of reception.  That's how it works in IT... either you're specific and on point, or you get completely ridiculed.  I hate it.  But, it is what it is.  The response you've gotten to this question is pretty much what you're gonna face in the field when you try to seek help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right out of the gate, I had a compilation error because `pickedWord` is being referenced outisde of the if statement in which it was declared.  So, by the time it got to `if (guess.equals(pickedWord))`, the compiler doesn't know what `pickedWord` is.

Comment: Any idea how I could fix this? I'm not exactly sure where to declare pickedWord. If I declare it at the beginning of the game = true loop, other sections can't find the variable

Comment: Well, think of it like this:
If (x) { declare a variable and run this code }
else { run some other code using that variable }

So, you can't use the variable in the else that you declare in the if because only ONE of those chunks of code is gonna run.  So, move the variable declaration outside of the if statement (preferably above it)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that popped out at me was the if/else ladder.

```
String scrambledWord = sb.toString();
      if (scrambledWord.equals(pickedWord)) {
          System.out.println("The words match");
          allTrue = false;
        }          
        System.out.println("Current puzzle: " + scrambledWord); 
        System.out.println("Current points for word " + wordScore);
        System.out.println("Enter (g)uess, (n)ew word, (h)int, or (q)uit: ");
         responseLetter = in.next().charAt(0);

    }
```

Notice how you close your if statement before getting a response for responseLetter. This means, your loop condition: "while game == true" isn't properly being evaluated.